# How does work mechanics to dynamic generate services in Sylius?

Tags: symfony, sylius

How does work mechanics to dynamic generate services in Sylius, which then are available like normal services configured in services.yml file in method get().

I say about this situation:

**Extending base Models**
All Sylius models live in Sylius\Component\Xyz\Model namespace together with the interfaces. As an example, for Sylius Taxation Component it’s TaxCategory and TaxRate.

Let’s assume you want to add “zone” field to the Sylius tax rates.

Firstly, you need to create your own TaxRate class, which will extend the base model.

`namespace Acme\Bundle\ShopBundle\Entity;`

use Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\ZoneInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Taxation\Model\TaxRate as BaseTaxRate;

class TaxRate extends BaseTaxRate
{
    private $zone;

```
public function getZone()
{
    return $this->zone;
}

public function setZone(ZoneInterface $zone)
{
    $this->zone = $zone;

    return $this;
}
```

}

Finally, you configure your class in app/config/config.yml file.

`sylius_taxation:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        tax_rate:
            model: Acme\ShopBundle\Entity\TaxRate # Your tax rate entity.`

Sylius automatically generates an access to the class like normal services.

- Parameter sylius.model.tax_rate.class contains Acme\Bundle\ShopBundle\Entity\TaxRate.
- sylius.repository.tax_rate represents Doctrine repository for your new class.
- sylius.manager.tax_rate represents Doctrine object manager for your new class.
  d- sylius.controller.tax_rate represents the controller for your new class.

**How works it? Is it a bundle? This is very fine solution. I'll would like implement the mechanics in my own project in Symfony2.**

Comment: Not only that but the resource bundle gives you CRUD funtionality out of the box in the ResourceController class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this in your own projects, simply integrate the SyliusResourceBundle via composer. Now you can define a resource in your config with given classes.

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.entity_name:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            object_manager: default
            templates: App:User
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\EntityName
                interface: App\Entity\EntityNameInterface
```

The available services are now `app.model.entity_name`, `app.repository.entity_name`, `app.manager.entity_name` and `app.controller.entity_name`.

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/configuration.html